# Challenge: solution for this deep-iteration JavaScript function dilemma?

Tags: javascript, optimization, algorithm, design-patterns

Trying to implement a deep-iteration function with some constraints, I've noticed the faster solution is iterating it twice! Any attempt to avoid this resulted in slower code. So, the challenge: can you redesign the function below removing the code duplicate and doubled iteration, without making it slower?

Constraints:

- It must deeply iterate through a tree, providing, for a callback function, the node value and it's path.
- It must work for arrays and objects.
- Arrays must be iterated by ascending numerical keys first and non-numerical keys last.
- It must allow for early interruption by using "return", and must return that value.

Code:

```
function iter(obj,fn,iter_pos){
    var ret, iter_pos = iter_pos || [];
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; ++i)
        if (ret = typeof(obj[i]) == "object" ? iter(obj[i],fn,iter_pos.concat(i)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(i),obj[i]))
            return ret;
    for (var key in obj)
        if (isNaN(Number(key)))
            if (ret = typeof(obj[key]) == "object" ? iter(obj[key],fn,iter_pos.concat(key)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(key),obj[key]))
                return ret;
};
```

Test:

```
var tree = [1,2,[3,3,3],4];
tree.x = 5;
tree.y = {x:6,y:7,z:8};
tree.z = 9;
console.log(
    iter(tree,function(path,val){ 
        console.log("Value ",val," at path: ",path); 
        if (val==7)
            return "Returned early!";
    })
);
```

Output:

```
Value  1  at path:  [ 0 ]
Value  2  at path:  [ 1 ]
Value  3  at path:  [ 2, 0 ]
Value  3  at path:  [ 2, 1 ]
Value  3  at path:  [ 2, 2 ]
Value  4  at path:  [ 3 ]
Value  5  at path:  [ 'x' ]
Value  6  at path:  [ 'y', 'x' ]
Value  7  at path:  [ 'y', 'y' ]
Returned early!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me start by asking how would you like to iterate over your object? Because what you are doing is not the same as calling a function for every property of an object.

> ```
> function iter(obj,fn,iter_pos){
>     var ret, iter_pos = iter_pos || [];
>     for (var i=0; i<obj.length; ++i)
> ```

The above for loop may access elements in the array that are not even defined. For example, take this array:

```
var a = [0, 1];
a[9] = 9;
console.log(a.length);  // -> 10
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(0)); // -> true
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(1)); // -> true
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(2)); // -> false !!
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(9)); // -> true
```

The above array has a length of 10, but it only has three *properties* (it has 10 *elements*, but not all are defined). If you do an `a.forEach()`, you'll iterate over the array's *properties*, only those that are defined.

If you do a `for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)` loop over the array, you'll get properties that are not defined. To avoid those, you should check `a.hasOwnProperty()`. Or just use the native `forEach`, if you can, that will iterate over the array correctly.

Note that checking against `undefined` would not be sufficient either, array elements can be *present but undefined*:

```
a[5] = undefined;
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(5)); // -> true !!
```

> ```
>         if (ret = typeof(obj[i]) == "object" ? iter(obj[i],fn,iter_pos.concat(i)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(i),obj[i]))
>             return ret;
>     for (var key in obj)
>         if (isNaN(Number(key)))
> ```

Here you're trying to do the opposite of `forEach`: enumerating properties that are not elements of the array.

But this code will miss properties that still evaluate as numbers! Have a look at the following array:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
a[100] = 99;
a[1.5] = 'this is not an array element';
a[-1] = 'this one is not an array element either';
a['20'] = 'this one *is* an array element!';
```

Also, watch out for rounding:

```
a[30.00000000000001] = 'this is *not* an array element';
a[30.000000000000001] = 'this *is*, however, because it rounds to 30'
```

But also for the string representations:

```
a[30.000000000000001] = 'array element';
a['30.000000000000001'] = 'not array element';
```

Especially the ones that evaluate the same:

```
a[1e1] = 'element number ten';
a['1e1'] = 'a completely different element';
```

`'-1'`, `'1.5'`, `'1e1'`, `'30.000000000000001'`, etc. can all be properties of an array, but they will all evaluate `false` for `isNaN(Number(key))`.

> ```
>             if (ret = typeof(obj[key]) == "object" ? iter(obj[key],fn,iter_pos.concat(key)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(key),obj[key]))
>                 return ret;
> };
> ```

You can easily fix your script by changing the line

```
        if (isNaN(Number(key)))
```

to

```
        if (!key.match(/^\d+$/))
```

, but unfortunately that makes your code about 18% slower.

## TL; DR

I've removed the double loop from your code:

```
function iter(obj, fn, iter_pos){
    var ret, iter_pos = iter_pos || [];
    for (var key in obj)
        if (ret = typeof(obj[key]) == "object" ? iter(obj[key], fn, iter_pos.concat(key)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(key), obj[key]))
            return ret;
};
```

and it does not seem to be any slower, or at least not according to [jsperf.com/iter](http://jsperf.com/iter).

I tried it in a number of browsers I could find.

## UPDATE 1:

Here is a version that uses two loops, but is **much faster**. It will fix the ordering, but only in cases where the array indexes come before other array properties.

```
__toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function iter(obj, fn, iter_pos) {
    var ret, i = 0,
        iter_pos = iter_pos || [];
    if (__toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        obj.forEach(function (item) {
            if (!ret) {
                ret = typeof (obj[i]) === "object" ? iter(obj[i], fn, iter_pos.concat(i)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(i), obj[i]);
                i++;
            }
        });
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    for (var key in obj)
        if (--i < 0)
            if (ret = typeof (obj[key]) === "object" ? iter(obj[key], fn, iter_pos.concat(key)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(key), obj[key])) return ret;
};
```

## UPDATE 2:

This is your original version, with two loops, but using `forEach` and `Object.prototype.toString`. It seems to output the same result, but is about 2000× faster.

```
__toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function iter(obj, fn, iter_pos) {
    var ret, iter_pos = iter_pos || [];
    if (__toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        obj.forEach(function (item) {
            if (!ret)
                ret = typeof (obj[i]) === "object" ? iter(obj[i], fn, iter_pos.concat(i)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(i), obj[i]);
        });
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    for (var key in obj)
        if (!("" + key).match(/^\d+$/))
            if (ret = typeof (obj[key]) === "object" ? iter(obj[key], fn, iter_pos.concat(key)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(key), obj[key]))
                return ret;
};
```

## UPDATE 3:

This version is about as fast as the other one, but uses only `Object.prototype.toString` and does not use `typeof`.

```
__toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function iter(obj, fn, iter_pos) {
    var ret, obj_type, iter_pos = iter_pos || [];
    if (__toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        obj.forEach(function (item) {
            if (!ret)
                ret = ((obj_type = __toString.call(item)) === "[object Object]") || (obj_type === "[object Array]") ? iter(item, fn, iter_pos.concat(i)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(i), item);
        });
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    for (var key in obj)
        if (!("" + key).match(/^\d+$/))
            if (ret = ((obj_type = __toString.call(item)) === "[object Object]") || (obj_type === "[object Array]") ? iter(obj[key], fn, iter_pos.concat(i)) : fn(iter_pos.concat(i), obj[key]));
                return ret
};
```

Comment: Awesome answer! I thought nobody would answer this question. Thanks! Enlightening in many aspects. I had no idea numeric keys worked that way. Yet your implementation has a problem I have faced before: it is not guaranteed to iterate numeric keys in ascending order in some implementations (the double loop is actually a bugfix for this behavior!) Sucks, no?

Comment: Hmm, I've only checked that in Chrome, and there it iterated in ascending order. Let me try something else now (another double-loop idea that may be faster).

Comment: I'm not sure how/when, but sometimes it just doesn't iterate in the right order. I know it have something to do with defining numeric keyvals after the array was created, on safari I think. Very specific, but broke many things.

Comment: @Dokkat please look at my second update. It keeps the two loops, but uses the built-in `forEach` for arrays, and uses the regex match to correctly exclude array elements in the second loop. It is 2000× faster than the original code.

Comment: What the heck!? Hold on while I test. But how did you find that out? How did you even consider that regex could be faster than isNaN?

Comment: I don't think the regex makes it faster. `isNaN(Number())` will pick out false positive property names like `1e1`. What probably made a difference is the `forEach`. I'm not exactly sure though. It might perform worse if you have a very long array and you break at the very beginning, because there's no way (that I know of) to break out of the `forEach` loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7717/discussion-between-attila-o-and-dokkat)

Comment: sorry I was working on the conversion of some files. Oh I see, that makes sense then. Any idea why Object.prototype.toString faster than typeof?

Comment: I have no clue, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10656437/252239) shows they don't even behave the same… Oh well, JavaScript can still surprise me after all the years :)

Comment: @AttilaO. updates 2 & 3 need `.forEach(item, i)` instead of `.forEach(item)`

Comment: I can't get the typescript compiler to compile solution 2 and 3. Solution uses a undefined variable i, and solution 3 uses a undefined variable item. Yet I see the code runs here https://jsperf.com/iter, and I don't understand how it could possibly run at all with those undefined :-/